# How to make a regular expression admit only admits lowercase letters

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to make a regular expression that only accepts lowercase letters and does not allow uppercase letters and does not allow white space. So far I have this:

```
\S[a-z]
```

Please help me, I dont know how make that
I'm working on it in reactJS with the ant library, and I want to add a rule to my form but the regular expression doesn't work for what I really need

Comment: did you try this website? https://regex101.com/

Comment: `/^[a-z]+$/` will validate a string as having only lowercase letters. If the string can be empty, change the `+` to `*`

Comment: Thanks, I know this is a simple topic, but there are some things that really confuse me about RegEx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/^[a-z]+$/
```

^ - start of string

$ - end of string

[] - Character Classes

you can use + for one or more OR * zero or more

Comment: I can't thank you enough, thank you very much for your explanation some things about the regex confuse me a bit